# Admin Panel using Session in Laravel - Getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a simple Admin Panel using session in Laravel. I don't plan on using Laravel authentication. I'm getting an error. I realize that its happening because of the get method in web.php file, I even changed it to post but still not working. Kindly help, I'm getting the below error. -

> RouteCollection.php line 251 at
>   RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD'))in
>   RouteCollection.php line 238

**Login.blade.php** -

```html
@php
    session_start();
    echo isset($_SESSION['login']);

    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        header('LOCATION:dashboard'); die();
    }
@endphp

<html>
<body>
    <h3>Login</h3>

@php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username']; 
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($username === 'admin' && $password === 'password')
        {
            $_SESSION['login'] = true; header('LOCATION:dashboard'); die();

        } else {
            echo "Username and Password do not match";
        }

      }
 @endphp
    <form action="" method="post">

        Username:
        <input type="text"  id="username" name="username" required>


        Password:
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password" required>

        <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Web.php -**

```html
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin.login');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('admin.dash');
});
```

**Dash.blade.php** -

```html
@php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        header('LOCATION:admin'); die();
    }
@endphp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h3>Dashboard</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when are you encountering the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use the view for the initial get as well as the post on form submit. That's generally a bad practice and you're also using a lot of plain php outside of the framework, which isn't recommended.

Nevertheless, you can try doing:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], function () {
    return view('admin.login');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only written git method over there. you need to add the post method as well as you are doing both operations on the same page.

```
Route::post('/admin', function () {
   return view('admin.login');
});
```

Also it's not recommended to do like this above, As you are writing the code in Laravel blade files but it's like Core PHP. I will suggest using the controller for this. So you can create another route and pass that data to route access to the controller then you can perform the action over there.

```
<form action="/admin" method="post">
//your form
</form>
```

And in your route file, direct your route to the controller

```
Route::post('/admin', 'yourController@yourMethod');
```

check this link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you must pass the **csrf_token** when using the post method.
Refer the link about csrf token https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf.
Add the code below in your view file.

```
/////In your view file///////

    <form action="/admin" method="post">
    //your form
           {{ csrf_field() }} ///add the csrf_token field
    </form>

/////////////////////
```

And add the code in Web.php

```
Route::post('/admin', function () {
   return view('admin.login');
});
```